# Verifying Google app through Oauth consent screen - development/staging app

Tags: google-cloud-platform

We are currently trying to verify our app that uses sensitive scopes and after submitting through the Oauth consent screen with what seems like all the right info in place, we received an email from Google Trust and Safety that they seem to think our app is in staging/development. It is live and we replied to the email to tell them as much, but it looks like the case was closed in the meantime when I tried to follow up and my second email never reached them two weeks later.

Does anyone know what could give Google the indication of a staging/development app and how to not have that be the case?

Comment: This happens to me a few month ago, and I can not get my OAuth consent screen for my production app verified. No other reason as "your project looks like a dev or staging app" is given by the API OAuth Dev Verification Team from GCP. I have responded promptly, but no answer so far. Would also like to know what is the reason for this in year 2021.

Answer (score 1):

If the application is marked as internal this can give google the impression of being a development or staging app.

And for the case to not get closed answer the emails from the Trust and Safety team prompltly to get the process expedited the most possible.